# Where is "configd" process logging file?

Tags: macos

in macOS X the process configd log some information about ipv4 changes and dos changes to the Console application, all I wanted to know is where this logs are, there aren't on system.log.

An example:

```
0   0   configd 57  por omisión 11:22:05.861090 +0000   configd network changed: v4(en3+:172.17.188.9) DNS+ Proxy+ SMB
```

[image: mac console showing configd logs]